Intersection vs subclassing to narrow a `Record<string, any>` property type
I'm dealing with an externally defined type and a constant variable that has a generic user_data property defined as:
// in an external .d.ts definition

declare class Foo {
    readonly user_data: Record<string, any>

    // other members including private
    private __secret(): void;
}

declare function doSomething(foo: Foo): void;

declare const foo: Foo;

My goal is to narrow the type of user_data to include only the properties I intend to store there. So far I was able to achieve this by creating a new interface that extends the original external class:
interface MyFoo extends Foo {
    readonly user_data: {
        a: string,
        b: number,
    }
}

declare const foo: MyFoo;

foo.user_data.a = "hello"; // ok
foo.user_data.a = 1; // error - expected
foo.user_data.c = "hello"; // error - expected
doSomething(foo); // ok

However I want to avoid having to define a new interface every time because this is a recurring pattern with many different Foo types. A pattern that I would ideally want to keep simple and encapsulate in a generic.
So far I have tried:
// generic utility type
type HasUserData<T, U> = T & {user_data: U};

declare const foo: HasUserData<Foo, {
    a: string,
    b: number,
}>;

foo.user_data.a = "hello"; // ok
foo.user_data.a = 1; // error - expected
foo.user_data.c = "hello"; // ok - BAD!
doSomething(foo); // ok

I guess the problem with the above is that:
declare const x: Record<string, any> & {y: string};
x.z; // okay, but unexpected. I'd expect that with a | (union) not &

I have also tried:
// generic utility type
type HasUserData<T, U> = Omit<T, "user_data"> & {user_data: U};

declare const foo: HasUserData<Foo, {
    a: string,
    b: number,
}>;

foo.user_data.a = "hello"; // ok
foo.user_data.a = 1; // error - expected
foo.user_data.c = "hello"; // error - expected
doSomething(foo); // error: missing private members - BAD!

Here the problem seems to be that Omit also removes all private members. If there was a way to avoid it it would solve my problem.

You can have a single interface where you can change generic type that you'll assign to  user_data, see if this helps you: Playground

Please [edit] this to clarify exactly what your question is. Are you asking why Record<string, any> & {y: string} allows you to access a z property? If so, that's what Record<string, any> does. It lets you access any property at all. Maybe you want object instead of Record<string, any>.   Or are you asking how to have Foo and its subtypes act the way you want? If so, I'd say you should just make Foo generic as shown in this playground link. Or are you asking something else? In any case, please [edit] to ask a single well-defined primary question.

Foo is a part of an external framework that I have to use but can't control. The framework has many types that follow the same pattern as Foo, i.e. provide user_data property defined as Record<string, any>. My goad to is to narrow/restrict the type user_data so that it can only have properties I want it to have. And to do it without declaring an interface that extends each particular Foo every time.

The post still doesn't ask a single well-defined question. From the title "intersection with record type" and the "but why?" comment it looks like you're asking about the behavior or Record<string, any> & {y: string} and the stuff about subtyping Foo and private properties and Omit are all extraneous. Or, more likely, you're really asking about subtyping Foo, and everything else is failed attempts to achieve that. Could you please [edit] to remove anything extraneous to your question and/or make it immediately obvious to the reader what the question is?

(see prev comment) Assuming it's not primarily about intersections: you can't programmatically manipulate class types with private/protected members the way you want. If you can't modify Foo you can subclass it as shown in this playground link and then refer to the generic subclass.  And so you can just use a generic type argument on the subclass type.  (And note, the subclass can exist only as a type in TS and not really need to exist as a constructor). I'd be happy to write an answer like that if the question is [edit]ed to stop asking about intersections.

Extra questions rephrased. My goal, as I try to explain above, is to:

Restrict the type of user_data of an arbitrary externally defined Foo type with possible non-public members
Do it without modifying external .d.ts definitions (as shown above)
Avoid subclassing every particular Foo and use a generic utility type instead.
The rest are my failed attempts to achieve it. I do think they are relevant though.


If you do wish to write an answer you may want to address why subclassing works to properly restrict the type user_data property type while intersection fails to do it.

The title is still "Intersection with Record type" so I'm confused.  I might write an answer but only once I am sure I understand the question and that my potential answer addresses it. Right now I'm still confused, sorry.

Updated title, hope this helps. Ty

Subclassing and/or interface extension allows you to narrow properties directly without intersecting. It behaves more like Omit-and-intersect. So that's why you can't use a straight intersection. If your class has private members, you can't use Omit or any mapped type, that's a missing feature as per ms/TS#35416. But you can still subclass. So you either write T & {user_data: U} and deal with the intersection, or you subclass Foo. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer, otherwise what's missing?

@jcalz I guess subclassing or interface extension is the only way to narrow this property, and you can't extend a generic argument like interface MyFoo<B> extends B .... Thanks for clarifying that, if you want to put it as an answer I'll accept it.

The ideal solution here would be if the upstream Foo used the object type or even the empty object type {} instead of Record<string, any>. The type Record<string, any> is equivalent to {[k: string]: any}, a string index signature where each property is of any type, and therefore lets you index into it with any key and do anything with the resulting property. That means it's incredibly permissive and not type safe.
Furthermore if you want to be able to narrow that type, it would be good if the upstream Foo were generic in the type T of the user_data property. That type could be constrained to object and even default to object, like this:
declare class Foo<T extends object = object> {
    readonly user_data: T
    private __secret(): void;
}
        
declare function doSomething(foo: Foo): void;

declare const foo: Foo<{ a: string, b: number }>;
foo.user_data.a = "hello"; // ok
foo.user_data.a = 1; // error
foo.user_data.c = "hello"; // error
doSomething(foo); // ok

But apparently you cannot change Foo's upstream type declarations and are unwilling to fork it locally either. So you are looking for a different approach.

If a class has private or protected members and you want to narrow one of its properties without "seeing" the property type from the base class, then the only workable option is to use inheritance via extends either as an interface or as a subclass declaration. That is, given
declare class Foo {
    readonly user_data: Record<string, any>
    private __secret(): void;
}
declare function doSomething(foo: Foo): void;

you can write
interface MyFoo<T extends object> extends Foo {
    readonly user_data: T
}

and then refer to MyFoo<T> instead of Foo where necessary:
declare const foo: MyFoo<{ a: string, b: number }>;
foo.user_data.a = "hello"; // ok
foo.user_data.a = 1; // error
foo.user_data.c = "hello"; // error
doSomething(foo); // ok


Other attempts to get this behavior run into various issues.
Class/interface extension that narrows properties behaves similarly to the intersection of the part with the narrowed properties with the part of the base class without those properties, so interface X extends Y { z: Z } is similar to type X = Omit<Y, "z"> & { z: Z } using the Omit utility type.  But you cannot preserve private or protected properties with Omit, or with any mapped type. There's an open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#35416 to allow that, but it's not part of the language. Right now the only way to preserve those properties is via inheritance.
Often you could still get away with an intersection by assuming that type X = Y & {z: Z} behaves like Omit<Y, "z"> & {z: Z}, under the assumption that if Y has a z property, then the resulting z property of type Y["z"] & Z will be of an equivalent type to Z and you can ignore the Y["z"] type. If Z is a narrowing of Y["z"], then it should be equivalent, right? Well, often it is: string & "a" is just "a", and {} & {p: string} is just {p: string}. But sometimes it isn't completely equivalent. And since Record<string, any> is so permissive and not type safe, you can't ignore it when intersecting with Z.  The type Record<string, any> & Z is going to look a lot like Record<string, any>.
So if Omit<Y, "z"> & {z: Z} doesn't work, and Y & {z: Z} doesn't work, then you need to essentially abandon intersections. You need interface/class extension. And since such extension requires statically known keys, you can't write a fully reusable helper type like interface HUD<C, T> extends C {user_data: T} where C is a generic type parameter. You have to write interface MyFoo<T> extends Foo {user_data: T} and interface MyBar<T> extends Bar {user_data: T}, etc.
It's unfortunate but there's not much better you can do without fixing the problems upstream.
Playground link to code

Thank you! Very thorough analysis. I will pass it to the upstream framework maintainers as well.

Your last attempt is the closest so far, but the doSomething function stands in the way of getting anything done. May I propose the following:
declare class Foo<U = Record<string, any>> {
    readonly user_data: U

    // other members including private
    private __secret(): void;
}

declare function doSomething<U>(foo: Foo<U>): void;

declare const foo: Foo<{
    a: string,
    b: number,
}>;

doSomething(foo);

This approach simplifies things at the expense of making the doSomething function generic. However, it still works because Foo has a default type for user_data.

Ty. But the problem is that I can't modify doSomething or anything else in the external .d.ts definition
